# Using a shared pointer in a std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, c++11

I have a scenario where:

1. I launch a new thread from within a dll that does some work.
2. The dlls destructor could be called before the new thread finishes its work.
3. If so I want to set a boolean flag in the destructor to tell the thread to return and not continue.

If I try the following then I find that because the destructor is called and MyDll goes out of scope then **m_cancel** is deleted and its value is unreliable (Sometimes false, sometimes true) so I cannot use this method.

**Method 1**

```
//member variable declared in header file
bool m_cancel = false;
MyDll:~MyDll()
{
    m_cancel = true;
}

//Function to start receiving data asynchronously  
void MyDll::GetDataSync()
{
    std::thread([&]() 
    {
        SomeFunctionThatCouldTakeAWhile();

        if( m_cancel == true )
          return;

        SomeFunctionThatDoesSomethingElse();    
    }
}
```

So I have looked at this example [Replacing std::async with own version but where should std::promise live?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184377/replacing-stdasync-with-own-version-but-where-should-stdpromise-live) where a shared pointer is used which can be accessed from both threads.

So I was thinking that I should:

1. Create a shared pointer to a bool and pass it to the new thread that I have kicked off.
2. In the destructor, change the value of this shared pointer and check it in the new thread.

Here is what I have come up with but I'm not sure if this is the proper way to solve this problem.

**Method 2**

```
//member variable declared in header file
std::shared_ptr<bool> m_Cancel;

//Constructor
 MyDll:MyDll()
{
    m_Cancel = make_shared<bool>(false);
}
//Destructor
MyDll:~MyDll()
{
    std::shared_ptr<bool> m_cancelTrue = make_shared<bool>(true);

    m_Cancel = std::move(m_cancelTrue);
}

//Function to start receiving data asynchronously  
void MyDll::GetDataSync()
{
    std::thread([&]() 
    {
        SomeFunctionThatCouldTakeAWhile();

        if( *m_Cancel.get() == true )
            return;

        SomeFunctionThatDoesSomethingElse();    
    }
}
```

If I do the above then the **if( *m_Cancel.get() == true )** causes a crash (Access violation)

1. Do I pass the shared pointer by value or by reference to the std::thread??
2. Because its a shared pointer, will the copy that the std::thread had still be valid even MyDll goes out of scope??

How can I do this??

**Method 3**

```
//Members declared in header file
std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<bool>> m_Cancel;

//Constructor
 MyDll:MyDll()
{
    //Initialise m_Cancel to false
    m_Cancel = make_shared<std::atomic<bool>>(false);
}
//Destructor
MyDll:~MyDll()
{
    //Set m_Cancel to true
    std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<bool>> m_cancelTrue = make_shared<std::atomic<bool>>(true);

    m_Cancel = std::move(m_cancelTrue);
}

//Function to start receiving data asynchronously  
void MyDll::GetDataSync()
{
    std::thread([=]() //Pass variables by value
    {
        SomeFunctionThatCouldTakeAWhile();

        if( *m_Cancel.get() == true )
            return;

        SomeFunctionThatDoesSomethingElse();    
    }
}
```

What I fund is that when the destructor gets called and then **if( *m_Cancel.get() == true )** is called it always crashes.

Am I doing something wrong??

[image: Crash when checking m_Cancel]

**Solution**

I have added in a mutex to protect against the dtor returning after cancel has been checked in the new thread.

```
//Members declared in header file
std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<bool>> m_Cancel;
std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> m_sharedMutex;

//Constructor
 MyDll:MyDll()
{
    //Initialise m_Cancel to false
    m_Cancel = make_shared<std::atomic<bool>>(false);
    m_sharedMutex = make_shared<std::mutex>();
}
//Destructor
MyDll:~MyDll()
{
    //Set m_Cancel to true
    std::shared_ptr<std::atomic<bool>> m_cancelTrue = make_shared<std::atomic<bool>>(true);

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(*m_sharedMutex);//lock access to m_Cancel
    {
        *m_Cancel = std::move(cancelTrue);
    }
}

//Function to start receiving data asynchronously  
void MyDll::GetDataSync()
{
    auto cancel = this->m_Cancel;
    auto mutex = this->m_sharedMutex;

    std::thread([=]() //Pass variables by value
    {
        SomeFunctionThatCouldTakeAWhile();

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(*mutex);//lock access to cancel
        {
            if( *cancel.get() == true )
                return;

            SomeFunctionThatDoesSomethingElse();    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you wait in your destructor for the thread to end?

Comment: If I wait then there is a UI that will be blocked for up anything up to 20 secs.  I want to avoid this at all costs.

Comment: How about you use a `std::atomic<bool> flag` in your `MyDll` that you use to communicate to interrupt the thread. The thread's function then checks this `flag` regularly and returns if it's set to true. In your destructor of `MyDll` you set `flag` to `true` and then `join()` your thread (wait for its termination) which shouldn't take long anymore, because you sent the interrupt signal.

Comment: The challenge I have is that my function SomeFunctionThatCouldTakeAWhile is a Curl sync curl_easy_perform operation and there is no way to cancel this operation.  The only option is to let it timeout.  If I wait for this timeout then its too long, that's why I want to fire and forget.  If I  join() then it causes a delay.

Comment: Is there any method/design that I can use that lets MyDll go out of scope and for my std::thread to detect this and simply return without continuing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 2 is just wrong. That's a design fault.

Your first mechanism doesn't work for a simple reason. `m_cancel==false` may be optimized out by the compiler. When the destructor returns, `m_cancel` ceases to exist, and no statement in the destructor depends on that write. After the destructor returns, it would be Undefined Behavior to access the memory which previously held `m_cancel`.

The second mechanism (global) fails for a more complex reason. There's the obvious problem that you have only one global `m_Cancel` (BTW, `m_` is a really misleading prefix for something that's not a member). But assuming you only have one `MyDll`, it can still fail for threading reasons. What you wanted was not a `shared_ptr` but a `std::atomic<bool>`. That is safe for access from multiple threads

[edit]
And your third mechanism fails because `[=]` captures names from the enclosing scope. `m_Cancel` isn't in that scope, but `this` is. You don't want a copy of `this` for the thread though, because `this` will be destroyed. Solution: `auto cancel = this->m_Cancel; std::thread([cancel](...`

[edit 2]
I think you really should read up on basics. In the dtor of version 3, you indeed change the value of `m_cancel`. That is to say, you change the pointer. You should have changed `*m_cancel`, i.e. what it points to. As I pointed out above, the thread has a *copy* of the pointer. If you change the original pointer, the thread will continue to point to the old value. (This is unrelated to smart pointers, dumb pointers behave the same).

Comment: If I use a std::atomic<bool> in the same manner, wont it still go out of scope when MyDlls destructor is called??

Comment: @HarryBoy: If `m_cancel` is a member as the name suggests (but unlike your example code), then it will go out of scope. You'd then need a `shared_ptr<atomic<bool>>`.

Comment: Apologies, yes its a member, I should have explained it better in my code.  So even it goes out of scope and I use a shared_ptr<atomic<bool>> will the std::thread still have a valid copy of it that I can access?? Do I need to pass it by value [=] or reference [&] to the std::thread??

Comment: @HarryBoy: The thread needs its own `shared_ptr` copy to keep the `atomic<bool>` alive. This second pointer will outlive the dtor. An alternative is to `join()` your thread in the dtor, after setting `m_cancel`. This means the dtor will wait for the thread to exit, and thus `m_cancel` will be destoyed only after the thread finishes.

Comment: MSalters can you see my edit please.  I appreciate your help on this.

Comment: I have tried to do what you suggested and it does not crash now but the value of `m_Cancel` does not change when I set it to true. If I use `std::thread([cancel] or std::thread([=]` it still does not matter.

Comment: Thank you very much you have been very helpful MSSalters you have helped me solve my problem.